# NSIS XML Parsing Multiple files

Tags: xml, installation, nsis

I have an installer, which modifies multiple xml files. For that purpose I have created the following macro. For the first file, it runs smoothly, but for the second one it throws VS++ error in my face

```
!macro WriteConfig File

   nsisXML::create
   nsisXML::load ${File}
   nsisXML::select '/configuration/connectionStrings/add'
   nsisXML::setAttribute 'connectionString' 'EF blah blah'
   nsisXML::save ${File}
!macroend
```

Any idea why???

Answer (score 0):

Have the XML files the same structure?

E.g. you are looking for the same XPath: '/configuration/connectionStrings/add' but you are not checking the returned values in $1 and $2.

If not found, reference will be **0** (zero) - are you getting non-zero values?